# Understanding a low pass filter used in a HV circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, low-pass

I have been given the following circuit:

[image]

The input of this circuit is a 3.3 kV DC signal. The filter is there to stabilize high frequency ripples that might appear on the supply line.

As far as I can see, this is a 3rd order low pass filter (R11/C11 + R14/C12 + R15/C13...not sure about the last one, though, since C13 is smaller).

What I don't understand:
1) the function and values of the resistors in the "return" line (R12, R13, R16).
2) Isn't this return line supposed to be just ground? Any particular reason why they would call it "return"?

Final note: my assumption is that J5 is used to monitor the current through R16 (to, conversely, monitor the HV value) but I am not 100% positive on this.

Comment: It's just a bunch of components with net names. Nobody can definitively say really anything about it.

Comment: For question 2, it is useful to differentiate between Return and Ground/Earth as they are not the same thing. A return path is the path the current will take to go back to its source while Ground is a physical earth connection.

Comment: @Andyaka well, it is also not much more than that in the physical implementation. On the right side you have the input voltage coming from a generator, on the left side you have the BP pin, which is the load (a semiconductor detector, if it is useful to know).

It was given to me as "a filter for the HV line"; I can see the filter, but I am not really sure about the rest of the circuit.

About the return line thanks, that makes sense!